# Summation Identity: Index Manipulation By Real Number Constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the following identity correct?

For any $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a \leq b$ and for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the following holds:
$$\sum_{i = a}^{b} f(i) = \sum_{i = a + c}^{b + c} f(i - c)$$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is true **if** you follow a certain convention. If $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and $c\in\Bbb R$, in general $a+c,b+c\notin\Bbb Z$, so the summation with non-integral bounds is not obvious.

If we agree that summation with non-integral bounds means that you increase the dummy variable by $1$ for each member of the series, then your equation is correct. For example, we can say that

$$\sum_{k=1/2}^{5/2}g(x)=g(1/2)+g(3/2)+g(5/2)$$

but I am not sure that is standard.

If $c$ is an integer, your equation is well-understood and is correct.